# Adding a `UIView` as a subview is initially slow

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, load, subview

In my `UIViewController` named `MainViewController`, I have a reference to another `UIViewController` named `SubViewController`. It is defined as follows:

```
@class SubViewController;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
  SubViewController * _subViewController;
}
```

In the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method of my `MainViewController`, I initialize my `SubViewController` as follows:

```
#pragma mark - Init

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil; {
  if((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])){
    _subViewController = [[SubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubViewController" bundle:nil[;

    // Forces the view to load, in an attempt to speed up the adding of the subview.
    UIView * view = _subViewController.view;
    view.alpha = 1.0f;
  }
  return self;
}
```

The `viewDidLoad` method of the `SubViewController` does get called, and everything seems to be loaded, but when I add the `SubViewController` as a subview:

```
- (IBAction)showButtonPressed:(UIButton *)aButton; {
  [self.view addSubview:_subViewController.view];
}
```

The app slows down for a couple of seconds, and then the subview is added and everything is fine. The strange thing is, when I remove the subview and try to re-add it again, there is ***no delay***!

I assume the issue is a loading one, but I can't find any documentation on how to solve this.

Can anyone explain what is causing this slow down? Thanks!

Comment: A couple of seconds is a **really** long time.  You might want to use Instruments to be sure of what's going on rather than looking at view loading exclusively.

Comment: I agree, it *IS* a **really** long time. Instruments tells me nothing sadly. Is there anything in particular I should look for?

Comment: On instruments, run time profiler, start the app, you should see a spike.  Stop it, then in the area below, keep clicking the triangles for the thing with the highest milliseconds on the left.  Eventually you should get to something understandable.

Answer (score 0):

your code its not complete !!

i try to take your code and make new project -ARC- and its fain to me no delay at all 
try to use Instruments to find whats happen

Comment: Well clearly there is more code in the layout of the `SubViewController`. For example, it has a `UIScrollView`, which I add some over `UIViews` to. I'm wondering if anyone else had a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I never had issues like that. since you are saying if you don't load the second view it works faster. check to see what is in the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear for the secondViewController